# What happens to a monitor if it is stored as a value in a hashmap and is replaced by null

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm saving a monitor in a hashmap and in case of timeout delete it from the hashmap:
n
thread 1:

```
Object lock = map.get(lockName);
synchronized(lock) {
  // some actions
  lock.notifyAll();
}
```

thread 2:

```
Object lock = map.get(lockName);
synchronized(lock) {
  lock.wait(timeout);
}
// some cleaning actions
map.put(lockName, null)
```

My question is: what happens to the notifyAll() when I put null in the map? Is the reference for the lock gc? Can it lead to IllegalMonitoreStateException?

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking if `b` would become null in the following code.

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = a;

a = null;  // b won't become magically null
```

I suggest you go refresh Java basics before you continue with object monitors.

Comment: I think here is not scenario of 
b = a;
a = null;here the situation may like this b = new Object();
b = null; so b will start pointing to null.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians No. The `lock` variable has a strong reference to the object that was acquired from the map, so nothing special will happen.

Comment: I think your scenario will apply when we passed a object reference as argument and and this local variable of method start pointing to null,than original reference will still point to object not null.

Comment: I dont know is this -lock variable has a strong reference to the object?let me check lock object can not be replaced by map.put().

Comment: As long as the original `map.get()` returns not-null (which isn't checked in the code) the `lock` variable will be non-null. You might want to go through Java basics too, since you seem to be unsure of what is going on.

Comment: @Kayaman - In the OP's example he is writing the value `null` back into the map. So the next *synchronized get()* would give `null`. But then again, in the OP's code the value will be set to `null` at the end. So, curent code will not be a problem.

Comment: Yes.you are right, untill thread will not call map.get() lock will remain point to previous object,and this will not garbage collected.but this can call trouble when you will send back execution to Object lock = map.get(lockName); using loop or anything else.Right?

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians - In the code shown by OP, `map.put(lockName, null)` cannot execute before ither statements (of thread-1 and thread-2). So, it is safe to assume that `lock` cannot be null when thread-1 reads it. Now, due to some reason if `lock` is null, then the line `synchornized(lock)` will give you `NPE`

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is based on the object not being [reachable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1): "A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.".

As long as some thread in your program could access any reference to the object, the object remains reachable. It cannot be garbage collected, so its monitor continues to exist.

The Thread 1 `map.get` call will either get a `null` or a reference to the lock object. If it gets a `null`, there will be a `NullPointerException` on the `synchronized` statement. If it gets a reference to the object, the object remains reachable through the synchronized block.

Comment: By the way, there is a little uncertaincy in this definition: *"any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread."* Does object's intrinsic lock is also involved in such "continuing computation"? Or this refers only to the object itself?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, an object is "live" if there is at least one reference to it from the stack of any thread, or from any other live object.  In the examples above, there is an explicit variable, `lock`, that holds a reference for the duration of each `synchronized` block.  I don't know what would happen if the statement `lock=null;` appeared inside the synchronized block (Is there an implicit, hidden reference or not?) but I can't think of a test that would prove the answer one way or the other, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: *it probably doesn't matter*--agree, the question is interesting from theoretical point of view, I cannot imagine such case in real practice.